# Table or column name cannot start with numeric?

Tags: sql, postgresql, naming-conventions

I tried to create table named `15909434_user` with syntax like below:

```
CREATE TABLE 15909434_user ( ... )
```

It would produced error of course. Then, after I tried to have a bit research with google, I found a good article [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=409471) that describe:

> When you create an object in PostgreSQL, you give that object a name. Every table has a name, every column has a name, and so on. PostgreSQL uses a single data type to define all object names: the `name` type.
>
> A value of type `name` is a string of 63 or fewer characters. A name must start with a letter or an underscore; the rest of the string can contain letters, digits, and underscores.
>
> ...
>
> If you find that you need to create an object that does not meet these rules, you can enclose the name in double quotes. Wrapping a name in quotes creates a quoted identifier. For example, you could create a table whose name is "`3.14159`"—the double quotes are required, but are not actually a part of the name (that is, they are not stored and do not count against the 63-character limit). ...

Okay, now I know how to solve this by use this syntax (putting double quote on table name):

```
CREATE TABLE "15909434_user" ( ... )
```

You can create table or column name such as `"15909434_user"` and also `user_15909434`, but cannot create table or column name begin with numeric without use of double quotes.

So then, I am curious about the reason behind that (except it is a convention). Why this convention applied? Is it to avoid something like syntax limitation or other reason?

Thanks in advance for your attention!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It comes from the original sql standards, which through several layers of indirection eventually get to an **identifier start** block, which is one of several things, but primarily it is "a simple latin letter".  There are other things too that can be used, but if you want to see all the details, go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92 and follow the links to the actual standard ( page 85 )

Having non numeric identifier introducers makes writing a parser to decode sql for execution easier and quicker, but a quoted form is fine too.

---

#### Edit: Why is it easier for the parser?

The problem for a parser is more in the `SELECT`-list clause than the `FROM` clause. The select-list is the list of expressions that are selected from the tables, and this is very flexible, allowing simple column names and numeric expressions. Consider the following:

```
SELECT 2e2 + 3.4 FROM ...
```

If table names, and column names could start with numerics, is `2e2` a column name or a valid number (`e` format is typically permitted in numeric literals) and is `3.4` the table "`3`" and column "`4`" or is it the numeric value `3.4` ?

Having the rule that **identifiers** start with simple latin letters (and some other specific things) means that a parser that sees `2e2` can quickly discern this will be a numeric expression, same deal with `3.4`

While it would be possible to devise a scheme to allow numeric leading characters, this might lead to even more obscure rules (opinion), so this rule is a nice solution. If you allowed digits first, then it would always need quoting, which is arguably not as 'clean'.

---

> **Disclaimer**, I've simplified the above slightly, ignoring corelation names to keep it short.  I'm not totally familiar with postgres, but have double checked the above answer against Oracle RDB documentation and sql spec

Comment: I am still novice with how postgreSQL parser work, I am curious again about why decoding identifier like `"123456_name"` or `name_123456` is easier and quicker than `123456_name`?

Answer (score 7):

I'd imagine it's to do with the grammar.

`SELECT 24*DAY_NUMBER as X from MY_TABLE`

is fine, but ambiguous if 24 was allowed as a column name.

Adding quotes means you're explicitly referring to an identifier not a constant.  So in order to use it, you'd always have to escape it anyway.

Comment: Exactly, it's to reduce ambiguity in parsing. It doesn't help that in PostgreSQL a parser quirk means that `SELECT 123abcd` is interpreted as `SELECT 123 AS abcd`, ie even without a space the string after the numbers is taken as a column alias.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Okay, it got your idea. But it is because you include operator syntax there. How about using non operator syntax like `SELECT 24_DAY_NUMBER as X FROM MY_TABLE` it should be non ambiguous.

Comment: @CraigRinger +1 for `SELECT 123abcd` is interpreted as `SELECT 123 AS abcd`. I still missing the concept of ambiguity in SQL syntax parsing. Why `CREATE TABLE 15909434_user` is ambiguous with `CREATE TABLE user_15909434`. Sorry for stupid question.. ;)

Comment: @iwawiwi Forcing identifiers to start with a number lets the parser be simpler and report errors earlier. The standard specifies is, so PostgreSQL isn't really free to change it anyway. It's implementation detail; just take it as given that this is how it is unless you're really interested in the guts of recursive descent parsers.

Comment: Okay, I think if we continue the discussion about parser, it would be off topic here. @CraigRinger could you answer this question with your idea. Or improve this answer with addition of your idea. I would like to accept this discussion as the answer.. :)