# How to add a php variable to a postgres query?

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to create a table by the name of the number that user creates. So what I wrote as the Postgres query is

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$rNumber.'_Bus_Stops(
                id serial primary key,
                name character varying,
                x double precision,
                y double precision
                );';
```

I'm getting this error.

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "11" LINE 1: CREATE TABLE 11_Bus_Stops( ^ in
>   C:\wamp\www\cdap4\route1.php on line 138

Tried the same with double quotes as well. It does not work. Can someone help? It works totally fine if I remove $rNumber

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Show us some more code to support _it does not work_

Comment: Yes, sorry I added the error message.

Comment: Query need be like this:-`$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$rNumber."_Bus_Stops ( id int NOT NULL, name char(50) NOT NULL,x double,y double,CONSTRAINT ".$rNumber."_Bus_Stops PRIMARY KEY (id) );";`

Comment: @M_T Table names can't start with a number. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15917274/5447994)

Answer (score 1):

Since the table name starts with a digit, it has to be a *quoted identifier* (an identifier surrounded with double quotes):

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE "'.$rNumber.'_Bus_Stops" (
```