# Why SQL table name cannot start with numeric?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ddl

I am new to `C#` and `SQL`.

Using the following code I am trying to create new table and all went good as I wanted but the problem is: using `textBox` if I name a table starts with numbers (`123MytableName`) it throws error saying " Incorrect syntax near '123MytableName'"

```
              using (SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection())
              using (SqlCommand MySQLCommand = new SqlCommand())              
            {


                MyConnection.ConnectionString = " Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=TestDB ;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=1024; Pooling=true";

                MyConnection.Open();

                MySQLCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE "+textBox1.Text+" (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(50), Col money)";
                MySQLCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917064/table-or-column-name-cannot-start-with-numeric) but it did not help.

Anyone knows how to fix it so I can create table which starts with numbers?

Thank you

Comment: Using input from users directly in SQL code without any kind of sanitizing is a sure-fire way of getting security holes big enough for a wide-load 18-wheeler to drive through them. [Think about Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) whenever you want to do something like that.

Comment: You can't use a parameter for a Table name so you'd better investigate some other ways to prevent SQL injection. And after thoroughly cleaning and validating the user input, prefixing something like "TBL" should be enough.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude. yes I know, I am just building a test program for learning purpose. tnx

Comment: Your next questions: "I can't name my table SELECT", "I can't have two different tables named ABC", ...

Comment: The problem with doing this (or other bad things) "just for testing" is that it can all to easily turn into habits, *bad* habits. Better get the good habits from the start.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude. thank you mate for the important advice.

Comment: @user8074669, Regarding the why part of your question, SQL Server follows ANSI standard naming practices. Names must begin with a letter and contain only letters, underscore characters (_), and digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the table's name by enclosing it with `[]`:

```
MySQLCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE ["+textBox1.Text+"] (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(50), Col money)";
// Here ---------------------------------^-----------------^
```

Comment: it worked thank you, but will it work with "SELECT" statement ? I mean if I want to read data from the 123MytableName table?

Comment: @user8074669 yes, but you'll have to escape it there too - `"SELECT * FROM [123MytableName] --etc.."`.

Comment: @user8074669 same approach ... Select * from [123MytableName table]

Comment: OK I fixed that using the ["+textBox1.Text+"] .

Comment: @user8074669, I hope your table names never contain `[` or `]` :-)