# How to drop a constraint starting with number in postgresql ? For ex : 123_5_pk_not_null

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, constraints, postgresql-9.1, drop

While dropping constraint named 123_5_pk_not_null, I am getting syntax error at the start of constraint name.

Query:

```
alter table table_name drop constraint 123_5_pk_not_null;
```

Error:

> Syntax error at or near 123

Need to drop the constraint

Comment: try double quotes around the constraint name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table or column name cannot start with numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917064/table-or-column-name-cannot-start-with-numeric)

Comment: Tried double quotes as well as single quotes. But didn’t work

Comment: `alter table table_name drop constraint "123_5_pk_not_null";`

Comment: The above query will not work